# AVAudioPlayer duration is not matching with the actual duration of audio file

Tags: iphone, ios, avaudioplayer

I am concatenating 2 audio files. Then i am playing that audio file through AVAudioPlayer. The concatenated file is playing perfect. But when i want to get the duration of the audioPlayer it is showing me the wrong duration, 2seconds. But my concatenated audio file's actual duration is 7 seconds. Where is the problem? Thanks in advance for help.

```
-(void)playAudio{

part1 = [NSMutableData dataWithContentsOfFile: [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Mumu night its getting dark" ofType: @"mp3"]];

part2 = [NSMutableData dataWithContentsOfFile: [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Mumu night did you study" ofType: @"mp3"]];

[part1 appendData: part2];

audioPlayer=[[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithData:part1 error:NULL];

audioPlayer.delegate = self;

[audioPlayer play];

duration = (int)audioPlayer.duration;

NSLog(@"audio duration: %d", duration);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try calling `player.prepareToPlay()` before you can get duration. It will show you a more accurate duration.

For full accuracy try:

```
CMTimeGetSeconds(AVURLAsset.init(url: myURL, options: nil).duration)
```

Comment: "*This is an Apple bug*" Can you provide an authoritative source for this claim? Curious to read more on it.

Comment: Go open a playground, create an `AVAudioPlayer` and get the duration, it will give you inaccurate result, then call `prepareToPlay` and check again, it will give you the correct one ;)

Answer (score -1):

You should use this

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avasynchronouskeyvalueloading/1387321-loadvaluesasynchronously

in the example just change "commonMetadata" to "duration".